Variables dependency after unitary transformation
Currently working on tight-binding model with external field that induced an extra phase factor, e.g. Peierls phase $e^{i\frac{q}{\hbar}{\int_{\vec{r}_j}^{\vec{r}_i}}\vec{A}\cdot d\vec{r}}$ which will reduce to $e^{i\frac{q}{\hbar}\vec{A}\dot(\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j)}$.
Then if we consider nearest-neighbour and after Fourier transform, the hopping terms will give a dependence $(\vec{k}-\frac{q}{\hbar}\vec{A})$, which is in a form like minimal coupling.
My question is, if we apply certain unitary transformation; in particular, a Schrieffer-Wolff transformation like from Hubbard model to spin model or any other perturbation methods (for instance, Brillouin-Wigner perturbation theory); will the dependence remain? Or if not, will it still be in linear, i.e. it will become a linear combination like $af(\vec{k}-\frac{q}{\hbar}\vec{A})+bg(\vec{k}+\frac{q}{\hbar}\vec{A})+h(\vec{A})$, for arbitrary function $f,g,h$?

Edit:
Tobias has a request for equations or references:
let's say a Hubbard model in the presence of external magnetic vector potential
$$ 
H = \sum_{\langle ij\rangle\sigma } (t_{ij}e^{i\theta_{ij}(t)}c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\sigma}+\text{h.c.})+U\sum_i n_{i\uparrow}n_{i\downarrow} \tag{1}
$$
where $\theta_{ij}(t)=\frac{q}{\hbar}\int_{\vec{r}_j}^{\vec{r}_i}\vec{A}(\vec{r}',t)\cdot d\vec{r}'$which is transformed into Heisenberg model
$$
H_J=\sum_{\langle ij\rangle}J_{ij}(t)\vec{S}_i\cdot\vec{S}_j \tag{2}
$$
in the limit of $U\gg |t_{ij}|$ and near half-filling.
Then as mentioned, after Fourier transform, Eq.1 will give $(\vec{k}-\frac{q}{\hbar}\vec{A})$ dependence under dipole approximation; while for Eq. 2, which is indeed the question (but my question is not limited to this simplest Hubbard model, for example, one can add spin-orbit interactions), will the dependence preserved? or only in linear fashion as mentioned? (see this paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03269, Eq. 4 and 5, which if we are not in near resonant regime ($U\approx \omega$), Eq.5 will eventually gives the linear fashion behaviour mentioned above)
One can also have a look at Kitamura's paper: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.96.014406 ; while they did not explicitly show the $k,A$ dependence after the time-dependent Schrieffer-Wolff transformation.
It is also related to Floquet theory, in the case I am interested in; but most of the reference/literature did not talk about the k,A dependence. Maybe this reference is related to our discussion: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.02744 (html)

You should include more details, equations and possibly references.
